# Discord.py Self Bot using rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a selfbot using discord.py rewrite.

I'm encountering issues when attempting to create a simple command.

I'd like my selfbot to respond with "oof" when ">>>test" is sent.

Here is my code:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=(">>>"), self_bot=True)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot presence t u r n e d on ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)")


@bot.command()
async def test(self, ctx):
    await self.bot.say("oof")





bot.run("my token", bot=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

A self-bot isn't a bot that uses `self`, it's a bot that logs in using your credentials instead of a bot account. Self bots are against the Discord TOS (and you're not doing anything that requires one), so you should set up a bot account through their website and use a bot account for your bot.

That said, `bot.say` has been replaced by `ctx.send` in rewrite, and you're not in a cog so you shouldn't use `self` as all.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(">>>", self_bot=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot presence t u r n e d on ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)")

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("oof")

bot.run("my token", bot=False)
```

Comment: It is not working anymore. `on_ready` is not being fired

Comment: @Volatil3 Support for self bots was removed because it violates the Discord ToS.