# How do I make a bot code into selfbot(of my account) code meant if I give any command selfbot replies through my account

Tags: discord, discord.py

## this is a code for discord bot I want to convert this code to my account selfbot therefore how do I define selfbot in the code so that it works for my account

```
import discord
import time
import asyncio
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    x = client.get_channel(61993237976252417)
    b = client.get_channel(623205069084688394)
    c =  client.get_channel(623888107124555776)

    if message.content == '1' or message.content == 'ff' or message.content == 'f' and message.channel is x:
    
        await b.send('**f**')
    
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if message.content == 'b' or message.content == 'g' or message.content == 'g' and message.channel is x:
        await b.send('**g**')
        time.sleep(0.5)

    if message.content == 'u' or message.content == 'c' or message.content == 'cc' and message.channel is x:
        await b.send('**c**')
        time.sleep(0.5)
    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot Client is ready!')

client.run('bot token')
```

Comment: "Automating normal user accounts (generally called "self-bots") outside of the OAuth2/bot API is forbidden, and can result in an account termination if found." https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-

Comment: Please tell me code don't care about discord TOS  I want code please

Comment: [See this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52084579/6779307).  You'll likely have to pass your username and password instead of a token.  Don't be surprised if they rate-limit you, ban your IP, or deactivate your account.